# 404 Directory not found error in Dynamics CRM IFD login

Tags: authentication, http-status-code-404, dynamics-crm-2011

The problem is as follows:

1. I can access the https:// url to see an ADFS login page
2. When I enter the proper credentials, the browser shows that the Dynamics CRM 2011 almost loads in and then displays "404 Directory not found"

The amazing thing is -

1. I am able to access the CRM site through my Outlook during this period (when it does not go through in the browser).
2. I am able to login successfully using the same credentials from a different user account on my laptop or any other computer.

What on earth is the matter here?

Yelp!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the error goes away when you reload the page and "Almost loads" means that the navigation is loaded, but the content area shows a HTTP 404.

There are some issues with this symptoms which are fixed in Rollup 1. Another issue with a similar symptom will be fixed in Rollup 6 (which is not yet released).